# How to disable specific apps from starting during Tomcat startup?

Tags: java, tomcat, deployment

My company is preparing a new production box while the current one is running. I would like to proactively install applications in Tomcat container of the new production box but would like to keep them disabled (similar to the feature present in Websphere) - this is very important because some of the applications poll for the data from the database and starting an application would interfere with current production deployment. They would be enabled at the time of production switch-over.

How would I accomplish this? Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So, you want Tomcat to *never* deploy anything on startup?

Answer (score 5):

You can simply rename de WEB-INF directory inside the webapp that you don't want to auto-start to some other name like `Disabled-WEB-INF`, before starting tomcat.

Later on, if you wish to start that app, while tomcat is running, simply rename back the directory to WEB-INF.

Comment: The app does not run, but it still shows as running on the manager.

Answer (score 4):

add `deployIgnore` attribute in `<Host>`, and the value is the regular expression of the dirs you want to ignore, if you want to ignore *`foo`*,just set `deployIgnore="foo"` and you want to ignore more dirs,use regular expressions to set the values

Comment: This makes the application undeployed. What's needed is to make application deployed but not started.

Comment: But this is the best solution I've come across. It needs some work to start an application (because it's not yet deployed). See also http://www.coderanch.com/t/580390/Tomcat/Turning-off-auto-start-web

Comment: On Ubuntu, the config file is `/etc/tomcat7/server.xml`, and `deployIgnore` is an attribute of `Host`. Not being deployed implies that it does not show on the manager, and that is why it's harder to start.

Answer (score 1):

You can use tomcat web application manager; this webapp does let you stop any application inside tomcat from running.

Comment: Thanks, but the requirement is that the applications to not to start automatically whenever Tomcat is recycled- for example by a reboot - otherwise, if the new app(s) start running, they could pull the data from production database thus interfering with the current production install.

Answer (score 1):

In the `<Host>` element of your `conf/server.xml` put `deployOnStartup="false"`. Reference: [Tomcat Host documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/host.html#Common_Attributes)

Comment: This disables deploying all applications, including the "manager" application. What's needed is to keep deploying the application(s) automatically but not start it.