# How do I configure Tomcat to NOT auto-start certain applications on Tomcat startup?

Tags: tomcat, startup

I have a web application deployed into an instance of Tomcat. I would like to be able to configure tomcat to not auto-start that application when Tomcat itself is started. However, I do want Tomcat Manager to be started so that, as required, I can start and stop the web application manually.

How do I convince Tomcat to work this way?

Comment: Possible same on Server Fault: http://serverfault.com/questions/333375/is-it-possible-to-turn-off-auto-start-for-some-but-not-all-app-servers-deploye

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable specific apps in Tomcat?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067062/how-to-disable-specific-apps-in-tomcat), given the comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067062/how-to-disable-specific-apps-in-tomcat#comment5675158_5067189

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible.

The closest way to do so seems to be this :

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Deploy_A_New_Application_from_a_Local_Path

You can manage to have the app not being deployed, but already present on the file system, and deployable using the Tomcat manager.

But if I am not mistaken, deploying an app will automatically START it as well.