# Java EE - selectively disable web contexts on startup

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, jboss7.x, java-ee-6

I have a Jave EE6 web application packaged as an EAR running on JBoss AS 7.2, it has 3 sub modules (WAR's) each with their own web context, at the moment all web contexts start automatically on application deployment.

Is it possible to configure the WAR's web contexts to be disabled by default on startup? I would like to be able to selectively enable each web context based on some startup logic in my `@Startup` bean

### Added for clarity:

I have seen solutions such as these:

[How to disable specific apps from starting during Tomcat startup?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067062/how-to-disable-specific-apps-from-starting-during-tomcat-startup)

Which invloves changing the content of the packaged WAR or setting a 'dodeploy' flag which I want to avoid. I would like to start my EAR application with all web contexts disabled by default, then once the application is fully initialised selectively start individual web contexts.

Comment: Is it not a server setting, to start an application automatically on startup, or not?

Comment: possibly, the problem I have is that I want the main EAR application to startup but not the web contexts, I want to selectivley start these after the main application has initialised

Comment: the easiest way to disable them manually after the deployment :)

Comment: @DaveB what is the point of "disabling"? why not just put some _servlet filter_ in each webapp, such that it doesn't let requests in until some `@Startup` bean finishes initialization?